# Linq query to get distinct object based on date and priority

Tags: c#, linq, c#-8.0

I have a list of objects with a DateTime and Priority properties.

```
public class DayResponse
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

There can be objects with the same date but different priority (1 being highest priority, 6 the lowest) and then I want to get the one with highest (lowest int value) priority. So the result should be a list with objects with all unique dates, and where there were "conflicts" the one with highest priority is the one in the result. Is there a linqquery to perform this? I know I can get the distinct dates and then loop over them and if there is more than one on the same date get the highest priority but there is always nice with linq :) I have MoreLinq package so DistinctBy exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can group the entries by their `Date` and then select the one with lowest `Priority` using `MinBy`.

```cs
sequence.GroupBy(d => d.Date).Select(g => g.MinBy(d => d.Priority));
```

`MinBy` is available out of the box in `System.Linq` since `.NET 6`. It can be also taken from `MoreLinq`, but note that in `MoreLinq` the return type is an enumerable containing all values that have the same minimal priority, so you need to use `SelectMany`:

```cs
sequence.GroupBy(d => d.Date).SelectMany(g => g.MinBy(d => d.Priority));
```

Demo for .NET 6:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

var sequence = new DayResponse[] {
    new() { Date = new DateTime(2000, 01, 01), Priority = 1},
    new() { Date = new DateTime(2001, 01, 01), Priority = 2},
    new() { Date = new DateTime(2001, 01, 01), Priority = 5},
};

var distinct = sequence.GroupBy(d => d.Date).Select(g => g.MinBy(d => d.Priority));

foreach (var x in distinct)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"DayResponse: Date = {x.Date}, Priority = {x.Priority}");
}

public class DayResponse
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
}
```

Available here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/SLnkSr

Comment: My bad to not specify the c# version so some parts of the provided code I have to rewrite but since running this in Core 3.1 c# 8 I don't know if there is some language capabilities I'm missing but for me the distinct is an IEnumerable<IExtremaEnumerable<DayResponse>> and the x can't resolve Date or Priority

Comment: @Hyzac My bad, I forgot MoreLinq has a different signature of `MinBy` and returns all elements that have the same value by which you want to minimise. Updated the answer to reflect that.